# Can't call fseek with inline assembly

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

```
#include "stdio.h"
void fseek(void *, int, int);
main () {
   FILE* f = fopen("myfile", "rb");
   asm("push 2");
   asm("push 0");
   asm("push f");
   asm("call fseek");
   asm("add esp, 12");
}
```

gcc -masm=intel call.c

```
call.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `f'
call.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `fseek'
```

I have been trying to use AT/T syntax but got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can not write like this, since there is no grantee that symbol `f` would exist in the generated assembly -- it's merely a symbol in C.

The solution is to use [GCC's extended asm syntax](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). For example, `push f` could be rewrited into this:

```
asm volatile ("pushl %0"
               : /* no output operands */
               : "m" (f)
               : /* no clobbered operands */);
```

As for the function call `fseek`, I believed your code shall be alright (at least in my experience and on my laptop it works just now). What's your platform info? Do you have `glibc` or similar things providing the standard libraries of C?
Also Please notice you're using a weird declaration of `fseek` since it shall at least have a return value according to the C specification.

Just for your information, you may try this style of an indirect call:

```
asm volatile ("call *%0" 
               : /* no output operands */
               : "r"(fseek)
               : /* no clobbered operands */);
```

Comment: That second `asm` is not right, since invoking a function will clobber at least the caller-save registers.